# How can I create an overlay barrier that captures onTap events, but also passes them through to the widgets behind?

Tags: flutter

My question is: How can I create a widget that "watches" and reacts to tap gestures without consuming them?

---

I want to create a `TextField` that displays autocomplete suggestions in a popup overlay below the field when it is focused (similar to Google Search).

The overlay should close when the users taps the screen outside of the `TextField`, but **without consuming the tap event**.

For example, if the user taps a checkbox while the suggestions overlay is visible, the overlay should close **and** the checkbox should be toggled.

I looked at the source of Flutter's `DropdownButton`, which displays the list of dropdown items in a `PopupRoute` that can be dismissed by tapping the screen. Internally, `PopupRoute` creates a screen-filling `ModalBarrier` that captures tap events with a `GestureDetector` (but it consumes the gesture events and does not pass them through).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `GestureDetector` with a [`HitTestBehavior`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/HitTestBehavior-class.html) set to `translusent`

Comment: Thanks, that lead me into the right direction, though there is still the problem that the final tap event is only fired for the foreground widget. But using a `Listener` eidget with translucent HitTestBehavior works!

Comment: Yup, definitely use a `Listener` instead of a `GestureRecognizer`, +1 to both answer and comment

Comment: @boformer can you explain how did you solve the problem of the tap being consumed by the foreground widget by using a `Listener` ?